# Angular 2 : Select on change to return the item

Tags: angular, typescript, select, drop-down-menu

How do I pass an item on change?

I got this far:

```
<select #sel (change)="select.emit(sel.value.url)">
        <option  *ngFor="let item of selectlist">
            {{item.description}}
        </option>
    </select>
```

But I would like to get the "item" passed back on change.

I should get back  just the item object

{
    value: 0, 
    description: 'Home',
        url: 'http://www.color.com'
  }

but instead I get **'Home'.**

Here is my Full array

```
public  pagelist:Array<Object> = [
      {
        value: 0, 
        description: 'Home',
            url: 'http://www.color.com'
      },
      {
        value: 1, 
        description: 'Tours',
        subpage: [{
                    value: 0, 
                    description: 'Italy'
                 },
                 {
                    value: 0, 
                    description: 'France'
                 },
                 {
                    value: 0, 
                    description: 'London'
                 }]
      },
      {
        value: 1, 
        description: 'About us',
            url: 'http://www.color.com'
      },
            {
        value: 1, 
        description: 'Contact us',
            url: 'http://www.color.com'
      }

  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with :

```
<select #sel (change)="select.emit(selectlist[$event.target.value])">
    <option [value]='i' *ngFor="let item of selectlist; let i = index;">
        {{item.description}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: that get's me the value but I want the Item obj.

Comment: @ChrisTarasovs , please check it now

Comment: Do you have plunker for this ?

Comment: aaa it did work. You can also write it shorter  (change)="select.emit(selectlist[sel.value]

Comment: yeah you have also added the local varible , will you please upvote my answer then ?